# Why don't max function and group by work well together in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I have created a `Match` table and want to run this query:

```
select player_id, max(goals)
from soccer.player_match_stat
group by player_id
```

The aim is to find the `player_id` who has the max number of goals in this table. So, I am grouping the tables data by `player_id` and then getting the `max()` of goals, but the result isn't correct!

Match:

| player_id | goals |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 |

Expected Result:

| player_id | goals |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |

I would be thankful if you help me with this problem :)

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: On first glance this seems correct.  We will need to see some data to help.  See this post on MCVE: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: By using group by, the output is a table containing all the player ids (the group by is working well), but I only need the single player with the most goals scored (so I have added the max command but at the end I am getting a full table as a result and not just a single row as the max value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you need aggregate not by `max` but by `sum`:

```
select player_id, sum(goals)
from soccer.player_match_stat
group by player_id
order by 2 desc
limit 1
```

If you aggregate by `max` you just get maximal value of goals for player per game.
If you aggregate by `sum` you get total number of goals for player across all the games. As i understood from question, you have to calculate total amount of goals (`6` goals for player `1`).

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
CREATE TABLE Match_tbl(
player_id int,  
goals int             );

INSERT INTO Match_tbl values    
                      (1,2),
                      (2,5),
                      (1,4);
```

In MySQL or PostgreSQL :

```
  SELECT player_id
     , total_goals
  FROM (
     SELECT player_id
          , sum(goals) as total_goals
     FROM Match_tbl
     GROUP BY player_id
 ) as t1
  ORDER BY total_goals DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/180

SQL Server:

```
 SELECT  TOP 1  player_id
      , sum(goals) as total_goals
 FROM Match_tbl
 GROUP BY player_id
 ORDER BY total_goals DESC
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=614d8063d98d4655fece19b6ac9f0faa

> Result:
>
> ```
> player_id total_goals
> 1            6
> ```